# jQuery not setting global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched and messed around with my code for about 2 days now but I cant seem to find the solution, and I am hoping its something very small that someone can point out for me. Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00gdax7m/12/)

I have the two global variables, window.goal and window.sales, that are being set to 1 and 0. I would like jQuery to set them to the variables found on another page. I have confirmed that the variables are being populated correctly, but then they are being ignored, and the javascript is using the global values. Can anyone assist me with this?

it seems like:

```
$GetGoals()
```

is being called before

```
init()
```

and it is setting the global variable back to their global values

```
window.goal = 1;
window.sales = 0;
```

when they should be

```
window.goal = 500000;
window.sales = 200000;
```

The jsFiddle contains all of my code. The CSS and HTML dont really matter, its just the javascript/jquery i am concerned with.

I forgot to mention. Sometimes, it actually works properly and the variables are grabbed and displayed on screen correctly, but that is only about a 1 in 20 reloads from what I have seen.

Comment: You are calling GetGoals before init, and adding a race condition by relying on network latency which is why you only see it occasionally. You need to refactor this to force data binding to the DOM to happen in your callback of GetGoals

Comment: Could you give me an example of this? I am semi new to web development and jQuery in specific

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/00gdax7m/15/

If you look at line 17 I added a call to a factored version of your init function... I can't repro your exact circumstance because the ajax call fails on jsfiddle, but hopefully this gets you along your way!

Comment: This actually fixes the number problem! Thank you. The only issue is that now the animation isn't working and it seems to be stopping after 1 rep. I will play with this a bit, but thank you so much for you help!

Comment: I dont 100% understand what your code does, but I have used it to fix the animation as well. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: So the lesson to be learned here is "asynchronous callbacks"... Your $.get call doesn't process immediately, and instead has to wait for the network to come back and with the response. During this time, your javascript still executes and goes on its merry way. However, since you haven't recieved your response yet, you can't conceviably know the values of what you are looking for. That is why in the callback (the function you passed in to $.get) needs to call the bind function and update your UI. try reading this! http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of creating a valid answer in here:

The issue here was async callbacks. Although the data is being loaded, its not updating the DOM to reflect the loaded changes when the request finally resolves. The fix was adding a call to a function that takes the new state of the data, and updates the DOM based on that

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. I would vote this up, but due to the negative votes on this question, I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

try window.goal = $(result).find('#CurrentGoal').val();  as the result is a value, not text

Comment: I tried that, and the logs came up with "an empty string" instead of the numbers needed